# How to Always show "startpage / index.php" to new visitors

Tags: javascript, php, html, .htaccess, redirect

Hello i need to tweak an old website so that all users regardless which link they followed to visit this site (e.g. www.mypage.de/somecategory/) first are beeing redirected to www.mypage.de/landingpage.php.

It should of course be possible to go to "somecategory" from the landingpage.php and from there to "someOtherCategory" without beeing redirected to landingpage aggain.

What would be the easiest way to achieve this?

Thank you!

Comment: cookies ? ............

Comment: you can use `session` or `cookie`

Comment: localStorage would be my choice, good luck